# Get back running threads on returning back to activity in Android

Tags: android, threadpool

In my app, where I user can start downloading multiple images at once I use threads for downloading process and also show download progress. I am running multiple threads via ThreadPoolExecutor. Problem is when user opens one of the images(activity goes to background) and I lose connection to running threads. How I can get connection to threads back.

```
public void submitRunnableTask(Runnable task) {
    if(!mPool.isShutdown() && mPool.getActiveCount() != mPool.getMaximumPoolSize()) {
        mPool.submit(task);
    } else {
        new Thread(task).start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Beyond suggesting great libraries out there (Picasso rocks BTW), I understand that your thread pool is tightly coupled to the lifecycle of the Activity: when the activity dies, so does the thread pool (or better, you loose the reference to it, so even though threads may still be alive, for you it's dead :)

I suggest extracting your ThreadPool to an external class - a plain Java [singleton](http://markmail.org/message/bdmcodp5xx6qwdaz) maybe, or better an Android [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) - which can stay alive longer than the activity using it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use Picasso for image downloading, it's very simple to use and so effective : (it's one of my favorites libs)

[square.github.io/picasso/](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

`Picasso.with(context).load(pictureUrl).into(imageView)`

Comment: I use Picassa for showing image previews, I also want to download images to local storage, to be able display them in offline mode too.

Comment: Picasso does offline too, and if you wand to store it when download you can use CallBacks to retain Bitmap and store it at this time